# How to export a javaScript array using POI 4 Xpages?

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, export-to-excel, xpages-ssjs

Do I need to export an object that I dynamically amalgamate in javascript using POI 4 Xpages in Lotus Notes.

ex.

```
Var export1 = [];

export1.push ({
ValueA: "A",
        ValueB: "B"});
```

I need to export this "export1" to an excel spreadsheet (XLS);

If I can create a datasource of type "View" through this "Export1" I can use the POI.

I already use the POI for Views Normally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the specificities of the XPages implementation of POI, but using the default Apache POI the SSJS code to create a simple Excel file from your export data would look like this (not tested):

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.util);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel);
var i,j,o,export1,keysOrdered,wb,sheet,row,cell,os;

export1=[
    {ValueA:"A",ValueB:"B"},
    {ValueA:"C",ValueB:"D"}
]
keysOrdered=["ValueA","ValueB"];

wb=new HSSFWorkbook();
sheet=wb.createSheet("export1");
for (i=0;i<export1.length;i++) {
    row=sheet.createRow(i);
    o=export1[i];
    for (j=0;j<keysOrdered.length;j++) {
        cell=row.createCell(j);
        cell.setCellValue(o[keysOrdered[j]]);
    }
}

os=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\export1.xls");
wb.write(os);
os.close();
```